# What hostname to use for mysqli_connect() function

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I am fairly new to PHP and website development.
I bought a domain and I created a script that I ran in wampserver and worked just fine.
When I put it up on my domain I got the following error:
**Warning:** mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'omafanoc_click'@'hephaestus.jcwdns.us' (using password: YES) in **/home/omafanoc/public_html/clickvid/index.php on line 44**

**Warning:** mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in **/home/omafanoc/public_html/clickvid/index.php on line 49**

Cannot add to database
And my guess is the hostname in the connection string is what I am getting wrong. What should the hostname be on a live website? I used cPanel to access my website

**EDIT**
Connection string looks something like this:
$con=mysqli_connect("www.omafano.com","real_user","real_password","real_database");

Comment: How are *we* supposed to know what *your* hostname is? `localhost` is quite common, but only you (or your host) should know. This could also be permission issues with the MySQL user.

Comment: *"What should the hostname be on a live website?"* - You should have received an Email from your hosting provider for all settings. If not, then contact them or visit their website, log in and you should be able to see it via the control panel under "database" or similar.

Comment: Show us your connection string and we will be able to give you a better answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`localhost` is most likely the host name if you are using a cpanel server. NOTE You will need to create a database and a database user/password too.

Comment: seems i hadnt given the user rights to the database